# Meteor - Stop Reactivity on ONE variable

Tags: meteor

In Meteor, how can I stop reactivity on ONE variable?

I want all the other variables reactive except for this one variable. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to achieve that with [`Tracker.nonreactive`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_nonreactive).

Non-tested example:

```js
// Get a session value in a non reactive way.
var myValue = Tracker.nonreactive(function(){
    return Session.get('theKey')
})

// Use myValue however you please.
```

Comment: Is there an example somewhere? This doesn't seem to work.

    Tracker.nonreactive( function(){
         return this.variable.name
        })

this.variable.name is a data snippet from a Collection. I want all things in this collection to be reactive EXCEPT for this variable. This method doesn't seem to work for me (it breaks the page) and I cannot find any examples.

Comment: @Mcope, this inside your anonymous function won't be the same as this outside the function, unless you bind it to it. The simplest way is to assign the value to a temporary variable outside the function, and use this temporary variable inside the function to refer to the value. BTW, I updated my answer with an example that should work.

Answer (score 1):

While `Tracker.nonreactive()` is a general approach (can wrap any reactive source), for `ReactiveVar` you can use a simpler solution:

`someReactiveVar.curValue`

It's what `get()` uses too, [behind the scenes](https://github.com/eface2face/meteor-reactive-var/blob/master/reactive-var.js#L65).

Answer (score 0):

just create non-reactive varaible with "var name = 'John';"

Comment: This does not work. If the source for the var is reactive, the var will be too.